# How to simultaneously insert values into table from two inserts using OUTPUT clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables, Student, Teacher & StudentTeacher.

Student - StudentId, Name

Teacher - TeacherId, Name

StudentTeacher - ID, StudentId, TeacherId

I am inserting a bunch of data into the Student & Teacher tables, and I need to grab the two IDs, which are both IDENTITY fields, and insert them into the StudentTeacher  table.  I have tried this:

```
INSERT INTO Student (Name)
OUTPUT Inserted.StudId INTO dbo.StudentTeacher (StudentId)
VALUES ('Jimmy'), ('Bobby'), ('Nanacy'), ('Suzie')

INSERT INTO Teacher(Name)
OUTPUT Inserted.TeachId INTO dbo.StudentTeacher (TeacherId)
VALUES ('Mr Jim'), ('Mr Bob'), ('Ms Nancy'), ('Ms Suzie')
```

But that doesn't load at the same time, so I get multiple rows, one with a studentid, one with a teacherid.  How do I get them to load at the same time?

Comment: You don't. You can't have two different statements like this. How do you know those rows should be the same row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would handle this requirement with intermediary table variables (or temp tables) that have IDENTITY columns, and then use the IDENTITIES to pair students with teachers.

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (id int IDENTITY(1,1), TeacherId int)
DECLARE @S TABLE (id int IDENTITY(1,1), StudentId int)

INSERT INTO Student (Name)
OUTPUT Inserted.StudId INTO @S (StudentId)
VALUES ('Jimmy'), ('Bobby'), ('Nanacy'), ('Suzie')

INSERT INTO Teacher(Name)
OUTPUT Inserted.TeachId INTO @T (TeacherId)
VALUES ('Mr Jim'), ('Mr Bob'), ('Ms Nancy'), ('Ms Suzie')

INSERT INTO StudentTeacher (StudentId, TeacherId)
SELECT StudentId, TeacherId
FROM @S s
FULL OUTER JOIN @T t
 ON s.id=t.id
```

Comment: For some reason the teacherid column kept inserting into the studentteacher table, in reverse which threw everything off.  I added a meaning less id column to the source table and both student & teacher tablesm then used that as the join, which worked,  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can only `INSERT` into one table at a time, so you can only capture one table's worth of `OUTPUT` values at a time.

You'll need to capture the StudentID and TeacherID values and pair them together some other way before creating the StudentTeacher record(s).